# M1 to M2 Migration

Tags: magento2, migration

Working on a migration from M1 1.9.2 to M2 2.3.3 and have a little problem:
When migration the categories I get the following error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2-46-0' for key 'CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID'

Looks like I have a duplicate content in the table Catalog_Category......

Could someone help me to figur out what the 2-46-0 means?
I have not been able to find that row in the table.

Maybe there is a SQL quariry I can run to see if any duplicat content in that table?

Comment: i think 0 is store id, 46 is attribute is and 2 is entity id

Comment: Follow this guide for better result : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please go to your Database and find this table `catalog_category_entity_int` or try to run below QUERY in mysql

> SELECT * FROM `catalog_category_entity_int` WHERE `attribute_id` = 46 AND `store_id` = 0 AND `entity_id` = 2

If you will get two records same then please correct value of one record or if that is not necessary then remove single row and keep only one and then check.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: When I use the Query I get not results back.

Comment: Try to run this once **SELECT * FROM catalog_category_entity_int WHERE attribute_id = 46 AND entity_id = 2**

Comment: Still no results for the quary.

Comment: You're checking this in M1 DB ?

Comment: Yes I am on the live site

Comment: Can you please look into that table and search attribute_id=46 once ?

Comment: The problem is that I have attribute id up to 43 and then it jumps to id: 105

Comment: can see it in catalog_eva_attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101871/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-kasper-elund).

Comment: ID 46 is an all_children attribute in eva_attributes

Comment: Found the issue with the ID 46. It was in the M2 db.

Answer (score 1):

Please Run Below Command :

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.0/config.xml

php bin/magento migrate:data -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.0/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

- 2: category_id
- 46: attribute_id?
- 0: store_id

The table **CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_INT** doesn't allow 2 rows with those 3 columns duplicated.